# How can i direct "cout", "cerr", "stdout" and "stderr" to a single file from a C++ program

Tags: c++, stdout, cout, stderr

We have a C++ Web Service which spawns child process on every request. So, every child creates its own log file.
We bind the cout and cerr stream to a file to capture all the "std::cout" and "std::cerr".

However, the service uses another "C" component to do some legacy actions. The C component uses "fprintf(stdout,xxx)" and "fprintf(stderr,xxx)" to print the logs.

Those messages are not getting printed into the "cout" and "cerr" log files. Instead it is getting printed in the prompt. We need those stdout/stderr messages also go to the corresponding childlog file.

Is there a way we could bind the "stdout" and "stderr" also to the same file where "cout" and "cerr" are bound.

There are similar questions but that doesn't have multiple language code mixed example.

Let me know.

Thanks

Comment: Yes, use close() and open() to redirect file descriptors 0, 1, and 2. This is what stdin, stdout, stderr, std::cin, std::cout, and std::cerr are really connected to. You will find more information in any book that teaches basic, fundamental principles of Linux/Unix/Posix.

Comment: It may not be ideal in terms of ease, but if you have modifiable access to the "C component" why not just properly add in logging functionality?

Comment: Well, the legacy code is pretty big and we are not modifying that. Let me try with open and close explicitly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default `std::cin`/`std::cout`/`std::cerr`/`std::clog` are tied to `stdin`, `stdout`, and `stderr` respectively.  The right thing to do is to redirect the C layer and the C++ layer will look after itself.

If you're on a POSIX system, just use the `dup2()` system call to redirect fd's 0 (`stdin`), 1 (`stdout`), and 2 (`stderr`) to the files of your choice.